# Resize PIL image: ValueError: Unknown resampling filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

So I am trying to make a desktop-like interface in python with Tkinter, and I am trying to set the wallpaper but I have no idea how to resize it. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as box
import webbrowser
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window=Tk()
window.title('Label Example')
window.configure(background = 'gray44')

#---=Main_Frame=---#
main_frame = Frame(window)
main_frame.pack(padx = 600, pady=350)

#---=Wallpaper=---#
img_wallpaper = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('minecraft main picture.gif').resize(10, 10)) # the one-liner I used in my app
label_w = Label(window, image=img_wallpaper)
label_w.image = img_wallpaper # this feels redundant but the image didn't show up without it in my app
label_w.pack()
##wallpaper_image = PhotoImage(file = 'minecraft main picture.gif')
##wallpaper = Label(window, image= wallpaper_image, width=400, height = 400)
##wallpaper_image_big = PhotoImage.subsample(wallpaper_image, x=1, y=1)
##can_wallpaper = \
##Canvas(window, width = 1200, height = 700)
##can_wallpaper.create_image((100, 100), image = wallpaper_image)
##can_wallpaper.place(x=0, y =0)
window.mainloop() #Main loop
```

I have tried used someone else's code to resize it with PIL pillow but it does not work.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/edwardandreilucaciu/Desktop/Desktop Interface Project/Desktop Interface.py", line 16, in <module>
    img_wallpaper = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('minecraft main picture.gif').resize(10, 10)) # the one-liner I used in my app
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1865, in resize
    message + " Use " + ", ".join(filters[:-1]) + " or " + filters[-1]
ValueError: Unknown resampling filter (10). Use Image.NEAREST (0), Image.LANCZOS (1), Image.BILINEAR (2), Image.BICUBIC (3), Image.BOX (4) or Image.HAMMING (5)
```

Comment: ***`label_w.image = img_wallpaper # this feels redundant`***: `tkinter` has `OOP` api, if you do it in a inherited `class ImageLabel(tk.Label):` you don't have to **assign it twice**. Read [PIL.Image.Image.resize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize)

Comment: @stovfl: a reference to the image needs to be kept somewhere or the image will get garbage collected. Assigning it to the `image` attribute when instantiating `Label` isn't sufficient. It's one of the quirks of tkinter.

Comment: When you say you tried someone elses code and it didn't work, what does "does not work" mean? Did the program crash? Did it resize it to the wrong size? Something else?

Comment: ***"ValueError: Unknown resampling filter (10)"***: The argument have to be of type `tuple`, see my answer, change to `resize((10, 10))`

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: how to resize images in Tkinter

```
import kinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class ImageLabel(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        path = kwargs.pop('path', None) 
        if path is not None:
            image  = Image.open(path) 

            resize = kwargs.pop('resize', None)
            if resize is not None:
                image = image.resize(resize, Image.LANCZOS) 

            # Keep a reference to prevent garbage collection
            self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            kwargs['image'] = self.photo

        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
```

> **Usage**:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        lab=ImageLabel(self, 
                       path="minecraft main picture.gif", 
                       resize=(400, 400))
        lab.grid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

It's actually quite easy

```
img_wallpaper = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('minecraft main picture.gif').resize(10, 10))
```

you see .resize is not availble for ImageTk image object also .resize takes a tuple of width and height
Try this

```
img_wallpaper = Image.open('minecraft main picture.gif').resize((10,10))
img_wallpaper = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_wallpaper)
```

Comment: Doesnt work. Resize doesnt exist for ImageTk. It gives this: ValueError: Unknown resampling filter (10). Use Image.NEAREST (0), Image.LANCZOS (1), Image.BILINEAR (2), Image.BICUBIC (3), Image.BOX (4) or Image.HAMMING (5)